# Perl program won't run on arm6, but it runs on my 64bit computer

Tags: linux, arch-linux, perl, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to run [pisg][1] on my raspberry pi, which is running archlinux arm, and every time I try to run it, I get:

```
   Root ~>pisg -cf pisg.conf
   Warning: Couldn't parse -cfg option
   Could not load pisg! Reason:
   Can't locate Pisg.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Pisg module) (@INC contains: /usr/bin/modules/ /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/share/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib/perl5/core_perl /usr/share/perl5/core_perl .) at (eval 1) line 2.
   BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at (eval 1) line 2.
```

which can be fixed by copying /usr/lib/pisg/modules/Pisg.pm to one of the directories listed as being included in @INC above. Then I get

```
Root ~>pisg -cf pisg.conf
Warning: Couldn't parse -cfg option
Could not load pisg! Reason:
Can't locate Pisg/Common.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Pisg::Common module) (@INC contains: /usr/bin/modules/ /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/share/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib/perl5/core_perl /usr/share/perl5/core_perl .) at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/Pisg.pm line 43.
```

which /can't/ be fixed by linking Common.pm to the the above places. The program works fine on my archlinux pc, though..

Edit: I downloaded pisg from the sourceforge and that seems to work fine.. (it downloads already compiled or whatever it is you do with perl programs, and runs in the folder I downloaded in..) Also? I was wrong when I said it runs when I install it via the AUR on my pc, I just /forgot/ that I downloaded it from sourceforge, my bad. The package in the AUR must be broken or something.

Comment: Have you tried installing the relevant modules through [`cpanm`](http://search.cpan.org/~miyagawa/App-cpanminus-1.6941/bin/cpanm)?

Comment: Sorry, I don't usually use perl programs, what is cpanm and how would I install the 'Common' module through it? I assumed that Pisg::Common was a module specific to pisg. I googled cpanm and found [this](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=common&mode=all), but there were no search results for "pisg" and there were /a lot/ of search results for 'common'..

Comment: @Benguin - You sure all your link modules have been compiled with an ARM compiler? x86-64 and ARM are entirely two different platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Your problems all refer to missing [Perl Modules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_module), think of them as an equivalent to C libraries, they are tools that facilitate certain jobs. Many programs make use of them and need a particular module to be installed in order to run.

Perl Modules live in the land of [CPAN](http://www.cpan.org/), the Comprehensive Perl Archive Network, a place of Geeks and [Monks](http://www.perlmonks.org/). So, when a Perl program complains about `Can't locate foo/bar.pm in @INC`, you should head on over to CPAN and find the relevant module. This can either be installed from source or by using one of a variety of helper programs around. Detailed instructions on installing Perl modules can be found [here](http://www.cpan.org/misc/cpan-faq.html#How_install_Perl_modules) and in the references therein.

Briefly, to install Perl module `Pisg::Common` (since that is the one you are missing), you can do any of :

- Run `perl -MCPAN -e 'install Pisg::Common'`
- Install [`cpanm`](http://search.cpan.org/~miyagawa/App-cpanminus-1.6941/bin/cpanm), it should be packaged for arch but if not, this should also work ([source](https://library.linode.com/linux-tools/utilities/cpanm)):

  ```
  cd /opt/
  curl https://raw.github.com/miyagawa/cpanminus/master/cpanm > cpanm
  chmod +x cpanm
  ln -s /opt/cpanm /usr/bin/
  cpanm --self-upgrade --sudo
  ```

  You can then install modules like so:

  ```
  cpanm Pisg::Common
  ```

Comment: I get:
`Warning: Cannot install Pisg::Common, don't know what it is.  
Try the command  
  
    i /Pisg::Common/  
  
to find objects with matching identifiers.  
Benguin ~>perl -MCPAN -e 'i /Pisg::Common/'  
syntax error at -e line 1, at EOF  
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.  
Benguin ~>perl -MCPAN 'i /Pisg::Common/'  
Can't open perl script "i /Pisg::Common/": No such file or directory  `
When I run that :s (Sorry for poor formatting, I couldn't get the line breaks to work with the double spaces?)

Comment: @Benguin no, I'm sorry. You're quite right, the module is not on CPAN. I could have sworn I had checked but apparently I hadn't. OK, could you edit your question to explain in detail what you have done please? Did you download the source from pisg's page? Could you try that?